# How can I change the size of the payment icons in the Shopify 'Brooklyn' theme?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I am using Shopify with the 'Brooklyn' theme and i need to make the payment icons in the footer bigger. I've tried to change the CSS code of the img class to change the size of the icons, but i just could make them smaller and not bigger.
Any idea how to change it?

```
.payment-icons {
  @include prefix('user-select', 'none');
  cursor: default;
  margin-bottom: 0;

  li {
    margin: 0 ($gutter / 4) ($gutter / 4);
    cursor: default;
  }

  .icon {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .fallback-text {
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below style in your custom stylesheet -

```
.payment-icons .icon {
    width: <width in px> !important;
    height: <height in px> !important;
}
```

Update:
For your store add the below style

```
.payment-icons > img{
    min-width: <width in px> !important;
    min-height: <height in px> !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately it did not change anything. I simply do not understand why it is so hard to change the size of a simple image.

Comment: It is not an image but an SVG. Can you share your website URL?

Comment: Sir, you are my hero. Works like a charm! Thank you so much!!